# Reducir cantidad de codigo dentro del ContextDatabase en Api RESTful con net 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-5.0

Tengo una Api REStful con Net 5, en esta api estoy tratando de reducir la cantidad de líneas dentro del Context de la base de datos, esto para mejorar la mantenibilidad del proyecto. Para ello agregué por cada entidad una clase de configuración, esta clase después será instanciada para solo utilizar una línea de código en el context.

El problema que tengo, es que me gustaría que en estas clases de configuración de la entidad, pueda agregar entidades relacionadas entre si, pero hasta ahorita solo he logrado agregar una entidad por cada clase.

Configuración de la entidad:

La configuración de cada entidad se agrega en una clase que después se instanciara en el context de la base de datos. En esta clase es donde me gustaría poder agregar más de una entidad, pero solo se agregar una entidad por clase.

```
    class CommentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Comment>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Comment> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Comentario");
            builder.HasKey(e => e.CommentId);

            builder.Property(e => e.CommentId)
            .HasColumnName("IdComentario")
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

            builder.Property(e => e.PostId)
            .HasColumnName("IdPublicacion")
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

            builder.Property(e => e.UserId)
            .HasColumnName("IdUsuario")
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

            builder.Property(e => e.IsActive)
            .HasColumnName("Activo")
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

            builder.Property(e => e.Description)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("Descripcion")
                .HasMaxLength(500)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            builder.Property(e => e.Date)
            .HasColumnName("Fecha")
            .HasColumnType("datetime");

            builder.HasOne(d => d.Post)
                .WithMany(p => p.Coments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Comentario_Publicacion");

            builder.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.Comments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Comentario_Usuario");
        }
    }
```

Agrego la instancia para la configuración de cada entidad en el context de la base de datos, esta línea será una por cada entidad:

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CommentConfiguration());
```

Context de la base de datos:

```
    public partial class SocialMediaContext : DbContext
    {
        public SocialMediaContext()
        {
        }

        public SocialMediaContext(DbContextOptions<SocialMediaContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server="";Database="";Integrated Security=True;");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS");

            //modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>(entity =>
            //{

            //});

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CommentConfiguration());

            //modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(entity =>
            //{

            //});

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PostConfiguration());

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());

            //modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
            //{
               

            //});

        }
    }
```

Por favor ayudarme, para saber si es posible agregar mas entidades por clase. Gracias

Comment: Mira cómo lo hace Jason Taylor, en su charla [Clean Architecture NetCore 3.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OtUm1BLmG0&ab_channel=NDCConferences). Si vas a preparar tu proyecto para que sea mantenible en el futuro, esos consejos valen oro.